Do I need to do anything to premade salt water before adding creatures?
I purchased some pre-made salt water for a brand new tank/aquarium. Do I need to do anything else to it before adding animals to the tank?
This is the premade water: https://www.petco.com/shop/en/petcostore/product/imagitarium-pacific-ocean-water

read the instructions and cucle the tank https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm

As trond hansen wrote, you need to cycle your tank. If you forego this step, there's a high risk that your fish will die after a few days or weeks
